# Vertex Cover without integer programming

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming

Is there a way to formulate an LP(linear programming) for minimum vertex cover problem without forcing the variables to be integers (no integer programming)? The number of variables are not restricted as long as they are finite. I googled it for so long, but all I could find was 2-approximation algorithm.

Comment: Hi Ted! In case your question isn't well received here, there is a computer science SE as well which might be more receptive. Anyway, welcome to the site :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

[Vertex Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) is an NP-Complete problem, and (normal) Linear Programs can be solved in polynomial time (using something simple like Simplex or Ellipsoid algorithm).
So, the existence of a linear program that solves vertex cover implies $P = NP$, so isn't that likely.

For NP-Complete problems, the best you can usually hope for is some type of approximation (provided you want to run in polynomial time).
The good news is even though a 2-approximation may not sound great (it might be twice as bad as optimal, right?) I've heard in practice that they often preform much better than the provable bound.

Comment: Now I'm confused because one of my assignment questions asks to formulate an LP to solve minimum vertex cover problem.

Comment: @Ted You can either formulate an ILP to _exactly_ solve it, or formulate the ILP and get rid of the integer condition to get a LP for a _related_ problem that isn't quite vertex cover.

I'd suggest posting the precise question if you want further help.

Comment: The question was the following: Given a graph G(V,E), the Coverage problem asks you to find a minimum subset of vertices S, such that for each edge, at least one of its endpoints is in S. Formulate the LP for minimum coverage set problem and write its dual.

Comment: I think they want you to write the ILP, then remove the integer condition.  What this returns will _not_ be a valid vertex cover (it may have $x_1 = .7$, $x_2 = .3$, $x_3 = .1$ instead of $x_i = 0$ or $1$), but after rounding you get a 2-approximation, and it gives something that you can find the dual of.

Comment: The class hasn't even covered anything about any of approximation algorithms. So I'm pretty sure he wants us to give an LP that returns the exact solution for min vertex cover. The weird thing I've noticed is that he gave a similar question last year, and it was about hitting set problem, which is known as a NP-complete problem. The solution he posted for this problem was the following. Let F = {e1,e2,e3,...,em} and I have a collection of subsets S1 S2... Sn where union of all of these subsets must be F.

Comment: I want to choose pick some sets out of the collection such that union of those sets contain every element in F, and I want to minimize the number of sets. He defined a matrix so that for every i,j, A[i][j] = 1 iff e_i is in S_j, otherwise A[i][j] = 0. Then for every subset I of [n], define a vector x_I, where i_th entry is 1 if i is in the subset I, otherwise 0. Then the union of chosen subsets S_i1,S_i2,....S_ik contains every element iff Ax>=1. Then he formulated LP: minimize x1+....+xn  such that Ax>=1 and x>=0. Sorry for the mess here

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mark's answer:

It has been shown [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00753.pdf) that the factor 2 cannot be improved.

On the other hand, if your graph is *bipartite*, the relaxed version of the ILP gives integer solutions, since then the constraint matrix is totally unimodular.
So, this version of the problem can be solved efficiently.
See e.g. [here](https://www.epfl.ch/labs/disopt/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/chapter05.pdf).